# FileNotFoundException in android sdcard

Tags: android, file-io

I'm exporting a file in the sdcard, however, I'm facing a FileNotFound Exception (`04-12 01:26:18.494: DEBUG/Carburant(4568): /mnt/sdcard/Carburant/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat (Is a directory)`
)here is the code:

```
try {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard can read/write !!");
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        try {
            final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String fileName = context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.fileName);
            String fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "")
                + "." + preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
            File f2 = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileDir
                + fileName);
            String y = f2.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("HI Export", y);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f2);
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Carburant/");
            String x = dir.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("HI", x);
            File file = new File(dir, fileDir + fileName);
            file.mkdirs();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // out.flush();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Export effectué",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Not found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String x = ex.getMessage();
            Log.d("Carburant", x);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // copyfile(nom,file.getAbsolutePath());
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard only read !!");
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states,
        // but all we need
        // to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("CARBURANT", e.getMessage());
}
```

Want to export a file from `/data/data/<package name>/fileDir+fileName` to a directory Carburant in the sdcard.

Comment: Your path concatenation looks suspicious. I suggest plugging in some magic strings and seeing if that fixes the problem. When joining filenames and directories, I suggest trimming all forwardslash chars off of the beginning and end of the second and first segments respectively, and re-inserting the slash between them. Obviously that won't handle "..", "~", or ".", something you may also want to consider.

Comment: @Computer Linguist: No there is no problem with "." because i used this file in other classes/activities and no problem encountered. There is absolutely a mistake in the creation path . :\

Comment: I don't think the message could be clearer : `/mnt/sdcard/Carburant/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat (Is a directory)`. Change  `File file = new File(dir, fileDir + fileName); file.mkdirs();` to `File file = new File(dir, fileDir); file.mkdirs(); file = new File(file, fileName);`. That being said your code is a mess - use finally and don't use 1000s of variables

Comment: @Shog9 : you should reopen is not too localized at all

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(dir, fileDir+fileName);
file.mkdirs();
```

I think you have created a directory called `/mnt/sdcard/Carburant/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat` by mistake and now the code cannot over write it?

Comment: I removed the fileName+fileDir in this line : File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Carburant/"); (see 1st post) and always the same problem :( .

Comment: @@Preet Sangha: maked this :File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath(), fileDir+fileName);
    file.mkdirs(); same problem !